# Запретить вход по ip nginx

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, nginx

Вот конфиг:

```
#HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS:
server { listen 80; listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }

HTTPS - proxy requests on to local Node.js apps
server { listen 443 default_server; server_name мойдомен.com;
    ssl on;
    # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dsa.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sad.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    # Pass requests for / to localhost:8080:
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

посмотрите он работает на htpps.
Пробовал

```
server {
    listen       мой_ip:80  default_server;
    server_name  _;
    return       444;
}
```

и/или

```
server {
    listen       мой_ip:443  default_server;
    server_name  _;
    return       444;
}
```

Сайт умер.

И  конечно делаю рестарт nginx'a

Nginx проксирует node.js

И можно ли отключить лог ошибок(спецом ввел ./4524)
[image: error_log]

Спасибо!

---

Нужно закрыть доступ на сайт по ip И оставить только доступ по доменному имени.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   server {
     listen 443 default_server;
     server_name мойдомен.com;
   ...
   }
   ```

   уберите опцию `default_server` в директиве `listen`, чтобы получилось так:

   ```
   server {
     listen 443;
     server_name мойдомен.com;
   ...
   }
   ```
2. ```
   server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
   ```

   и здесь уберите опцию `default_server` и добавьте директиву `server_name`:

   ```
   server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
     server_name мойдомен.com;
     rewrite https://мойдомен.com$request_uri permanent;
   }
   ```
3. создайте секцию-заглушку для htts примерно такого вида:

   ```
   server {
     listen 443 default;
     rewrite ^ http://$host$request_uri permanent;
     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate /какой-нибудь/существующий/сертификат;
     ssl_certificate_key /какой-нибудь/существующий/ключ;
   }
   ```

   благодаря ей вы получите хоть какой-нибудь ответ при попытке обращения к `https://чего-нибудь`, если браузер клиента по какой-то причине решит обратиться именно к вашему http-серверу.

Comment: Не помогает.Так же доступен по ip

Comment: @ФаильХабибуллин, вероятно, тут некое взаимонедопонимание. чем, по-вашему, отличается «доступен по ip» и «**не**доступен по ip»?

Comment: Чтоб не давал подключится на сайт через ip домена.А через домен подключался

Comment: @ФаильХабибуллин, ваше уточнение технически невозможно — http-соединение устанавливается именно с ip-адресом, а доменные имена — это как бы псевдонимы для ip-адресов. введённые (в частности) чтоб удобнее было запоминать.

Comment: nginx вообще не любит строку rewrite https://мойдомен.com$request_uri permanent; Дай хоть пере направление с www.my.com на my.com не кушает http://pastexen.com/i/uPFTxeNLKu.png и 80 ставил и 443 не как

Comment: @ФаильХабибуллин, `server_name faildesigner.com www.faildesigner.com;`

Answer (score -1):

Правильный формат:

```
server {
    listen мой_ip:80 default_server;
    server_name "";
    access_log /dev/null;
    error_log /dev/null;
    return 403;
}
```

Обратите внимание на опцию `server_name`